# about python pandas.read_sql_query Any datetime values with time zone information parsed via the `parse_dates` parameter will be converted to UTC

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

in doc py2.7 pandas.read_sql_query :

```
Notes
-----
Any datetime values with time zone information parsed via the `parse_dates`
parameter will be converted to UTC
```

how i can  converted to other

```
sql = "SELECT `date`,`id`,`open`,`high`,`low`,`last`,`vol` FROM okcoin_btc_1min_kline_data  WHERE date>=" + str(start_time) + " AND symbol='" + symbol + "'  AND type='" + kline_type + "' ORDER BY date ASC "
btc_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
# btc_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, index_col='date')
# btc_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, index_col='date',parse_dates={'date':{'unit':'s'}})
conn.close()
# print btc_data
# btc_data.tz_localize(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))
# 查看时区 pytz.country_timezones('cn')
# tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')

# print btc_data
# exit()
print btc_data['date']
# date_string_list = btc_data.index.tolist()
print btc_data['date'][0]
print time.localtime(btc_data['date'][0])
print str(datetime.now())
print pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
print pd.to_datetime(btc_data['date'][0])
print btc_data['date'][0]
exit()
btc_data.index = [time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(btc_data['date'][x])) for x in
                  range(len(btc_data['date']))]
# btc_data.index = [time.localtime(btc_data['date'][x]) for x in
#                   range(len(btc_data['date']))]
print btc_data.index
# exit()

# btc_data.index = pd.to_datetime(btc_data.index, unit='s', utc=False)
# print btc_data
# exit()
# btc_data = btc_data.tz_localize(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))
# print btc_data
# print btc_data.index.tolist()
# exit()
```

I tried a lot of ways， but is not working

What should I do？

see that

```
print pd.to_datetime(btc_data['date'][0],unit='s').tz_localize(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))
```

and i get

```
2017-01-12 06:00:00+08:00
```

but i want

```
2017-01-12 14:00:00
```

and about python （datetime，time，timestrap）

who have same details doc

Answer (score 0):

I'm done！
there is a fun

```
btc_data.index = btc_data['date'].apply(pd.Timestamp.fromtimestamp)
```

Directly convert a as index