# SQL datetime CET to Python becomes UTC

Tags: python, sql, pandas

In my SQL database I have a date column with the type `datetimeoffset(0)', where the entries looks like this:

```
2022-01-14 23:00:00 +01:00
```

Which is in CET time.

Then when I try to load this into a Pandas data frame with:

```
    year = 2022
    month = 1

    columns = "date"
    table = "[dbo].[MyTable]"
    conditions = f"YEAR(date) = '{year}' AND MONTH(date) = '{month}'"

    sql_query = f"SELECT {columns} FROM {table} WHERE {conditions}"

    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection)
```

So I try to load all datetimes within a year and month so I get all the hours within this month.

The resulting `dtype` of the data frame, and in particular the column with this date is:

```
date     datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Hence, it is now UTC. And I can see that it has been transformed to +00:00. I could probably convert it back to CET when I have it in my data frame, but it's always nice to have everything as clean as possible when you load it from SQL.

So is this a Pandas problem, or an SQL problem, and can it even be solved without having to convert to CET again when I have it Pandas data frame form ?

Comment: can you show how you assign the data from db to pandas in Python?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I have updated my OP.

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364970/about-python-pandas-read-sql-query-any-datetime-values-with-time-zone-informatio